# How to store the letter of a string

Tags: c#, string, storage

How would I store the letter  in a string that has been removed from a word?

```
DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
RandomWord = row["Words"].ToString();
Letter = RandomWord.Remove(2, 1);
```

This is my code so far, it gets a word from the row 'Words' and then removes 1 letter from index 2 and stores it as Letter. Now how would I store the letter that has been removed?

Comment: `char letter = RandomWord[2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to capture the letter before removing it:

```
string Letter = RandomWord.Substring(2, 1);
RandomWord = RandomWord.Remove(2, 1);
```

or if you want a `char`:

```
char Letter = RandomWord[2];
RandomWord = RandomWord.Remove(2, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that answer is perfect! If I had 15 rep I would of rated it up, but thanks dude man you've been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

How about using an extension method and overload `string.Remove` ?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Remove(this string source, int start, int count, out char letter)
    {
        letter = source[start];
        return source.Remove(start, count);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string str = "Word";
char letter;
str = str.Remove(2, 1, out letter);  // letter = r
```